# Android SimpleXML Parsing seems limited in Depth

Tags: java, android, xml, simple-framework

I'm trying to read a config file on Android using Retrofit and SimpleXML.

I have my dependencies set up and a valid XML scheme. Simple XML begins to parse my document but when it reaches a certain tag/depth it fails with the error below

```
Caused by: retrofit.converter.ConversionException: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'Host' does not have a match in class
Caused by: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'Host' does not have a match in class
```

Part of my xml looks like this:

```
<Config>
    ...
    <Identity>
        <Address>
            <Host>...</Host>
            ...
        </Address>
        ...
     </Identity>
     ...
</Config>
```

It parses everything up until it reaches the `Host` tag which is the first element nested that deeply. The error given usually indicates a missing annotation, but the in this case it is annotated as it should be. My mapped object looks like the following:

```
@Root(name="Config")
public class Config {

    @ElementList(entry="Identity", inline=true)
    private List<Identity> mIdentities;

    @Root(name="Identity")
    static class Identity {

        @Element(name="Address")
        private Address mAddress;

        ...

    }

    @Root(name="Address")
    static class Address {

        @Element(name="Host")
        private String mHost;

        ...
    }
}
```

Is there anybody else who has experienced a similar issue and has an idea what the problem may be? Or is SimpleXML limited with the depth it can reach? Maybe it's an issue related to ListElement's? I can't find any documentation that mentions any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception indicates a missing annotation ***or*** a wrong mapping between class and xml. Maybe the nesting is not correct, a wrong annotation is used etc.

It's hard to say whats the cause here, but put make sure your code looks something like this:

*(Pseudocode, not testet!)*

```
@Root(name = "Address")
public class Address
{
    @Element(name="Host")
    private String mHost;

    // more things here ...
}
```

Can you test your problem on a minimal or show at least how address is implemented? Btw. is always helpful to try the *opposite direction*: Take a `Config` object, serialize it and check if it's constructed as you require.

Comment: Yes everything is annotated correctly, I've double checked and tried the subclasses with both Element and Root. Is there definitely no limitation with depth?

Comment: Btw I have updated my question with the mapping class

Comment: Please test serialization of a `Config` object (if possible), does it match your input or are there any errors too?

Comment: The XML comes from a provisioning server, validated by a schema, which was also used to write the mapping, it's definitely correct and in any case can't be changed. Last thing Friday I flattened the structure to 3 nodes max depth (ie host as a property of identity) and it just worked. I think it might be a limitation of SimpleXML or at least of SimpleXML when used via Retrofit

Comment: As a fallback solution, you should consider a `Converter` implementation (see Simple Xml documentation for further details). With a Converter you can implement the process of serialization / deserialization by your own. So there's no mapping problem, but you have to implement some things by your own.

Comment: Either I don't understand, or you don't. Simple *is* the converter for Retrofit

Comment: I'm talking about the [`Converter`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/Converter.html) interface of simple xml. This allows you to customize the serialization / deserialization as you like. This is the fallback solution if everything else fails. Btw. you don't have to implement the complete (de-)serialization process, only the things that you need / want.

Comment: But as i said before, the best way to see where the problem comes from is: take a `Config` object, fill it with some testing data and let simple serialize it. Then check if the output is correct (completely exclude input xml / server), just serialize some test data.

Comment: On more: the messages from the server don't change or may be corrupted?